# Filepaths in Wampserver and PHP

Tags: php, filesystems, wamp, wampserver, filepath

Trying to use Filesystem functions in a Wampserver environment and cannot read or open files.

Ran these:

```
echo dirname('c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/test.php');

$basename = basename('c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/');
var_dump($basename);

$pathinfo = pathinfo('c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/');
var_dump($pathinfo);

$realpath = realpath('c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/test.php');
var_dump($realpath);
```

which returned:

```
c:/wamp/localhost/www/test
string 'test' (length=4)
array (size=3)
  'dirname' => string 'c:/wamp/localhost/www' (length=21)
  'basename' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'filename' => string 'test' (length=4)
boolean false
```

but:

```
$match_id = file('c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/ccg_wcp.csv');
```

gives me:

> Warning: file(c:/wamp/localhost/www/test/ccg_wcp.csv): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line
>   32

Coming from Linux, don't understand Windows filepath settings. The file is there, wampserver is not seeing it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a relative path, especially if the wanted file is within your web root? Also, your `realpath` returned `false`, meaning it wasn't found, try `realpath('/wamp/localhost/www/test/ccg_wcp.csv');` and it should convert it to a string that you can then use.

Comment: Thx, I just tried realpath with the relative path but it still returned false. I used the full 'c:' path because I was trying to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: Don't use the `c:`, as it will convert it for you by default.  Also, a more direct approach would be using the correct backslash, ie `realpath('c:\wamp\localhost\www\test\ccg_wcp.csv');`